# How to reload or deploy Tomcat Application without using Tomcat Manager

Tags: linux, tomcat, server, tomcat8

I am in search of how to start/stop/reload an application present in tomcat webapps without restarting tomcat or without using tomcat manager.

In my case tomcat manager is blocked. So how can i achieve this.

Comment: Why not  just redeploying it?!!!

Comment: Hi, @KLajdPaja. how can i redeploy my war file. because when ever i replace old war file with updated war file. i have to restart my tomcat because of tomcat hardening war file is not auto deployed. Each time when i have to deploy war file i have to manually restart tomcat. i there any possible way to redeploy war without restarting tomcat.